# iCloud NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification only called right after app launch

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, nsnotificationcenter, uimanageddocument

My app uses a core data database contained inside of a UIManagedDocument.  When I am attempting to sync over iCloud, the data rarely gets refreshed.  I have turned on the ubiquity logs by adding the following app argument to my scheme.

```
-com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.logLevel 3
```

The argument log output shows that the destination device recognizes the changes soon after they are made on a source device, yet the `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` notification is not triggered.  Occasionally, the notification will get triggered a substantial amount of time after the updates have been seen, but usually not.

However, when I re-launch the app (at any time after the log has printed some text about the changes), the  `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` notification is triggered immediately, causing the data to refresh.

Note: I have subscribed to the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(updatedFromCloud:)
                                            name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                          object:nil];
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, and I'm passing the persistent store coordinator as object parameter. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the object to the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator that you're using so that the notification knows which object to listen to. You've set it to nil in your code.

Example:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                    selector:@selector(updatedFromCloud:)
                                        name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                      object:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

If you're posting the observer in a class that has access to the NSManagedObjectContext (but not the coordinator), you can simply extract the coordinator via self.managedObjectContext.persistendStoreCoordinator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm passing the persistent store coordinator (there's only 1) as object parameter. So I assume it's caused by something else. Any idea?